# invoking shell "source" via ssh

Tags: ssh, sh

[ I am going to use `/dev/null` to illustrate the problem.  If that bothers you, just replace it with any other shell initialization file, such as `/etc/profile`. ]

I am trying to invoke `source` within a shell called by `ssh`.
The following works:

```
host$ source /dev/null
host$ sh -c 'source /dev/null'
```

But the following fails:

```
host$ ssh localhost sh -c 'source /dev/null'
/dev/null: line 0: source: filename argument required
source: usage: source filename [arguments]
```

But if I make `source` the second command in the shell, then it works:

```
host$ ssh localhost sh -c 'echo; source /dev/null'
```

```
host$ ssh localhost sh -c ':; source /dev/null'
host$
```

The question is why cannot I invoke `source` as the first command in a shell through ssh?  And how to do it properly?  (And for a bonus answer, why does it work when it is the second command?)
[ And the `source` command will not be the only command called; it is just a requirement before I invoke the other commands on the same ssh command. ]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your quoting is incomplete.

`sh -c 'source /dev/null'` invokes a new shell and passes it two parameters, the first is the option (`-c`), the second is the command-string for `-c` to operate on.

`ssh localhost sh -c 'source /dev/null'` invokes ssh to start a shell on localhost. This new shell is passed a command containing **4** words - in effect, the single-quotes are removed by ssh. This shell duly starts a second shell and passes it **3** parameters. In this case `-c` only receives `source` as the command-string.

You need additional quoting to replace the ones stripped by ssh. For example:

```
ssh localhost "sh -c 'source /dev/null'"
```

The reason `ssh localhost sh -c 'echo; source /dev/null'` appears to  work is that ssh has passed two commands to the shell it starts: `sh -c echo` (which then exits), followed by `source /dev/null`

It may be helpful to imagine replacing `ssh localhost` with `echo` and seeing which quotes disappear.

---

The [POSIX shell synopsis](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sh.html) says:

> ```
> sh -c [-abCefhimnuvx] [-o option]... [+abCefhimnuvx] [+o option]...
>    command_string [command_name [argument...]]
>
> -c   Read commands from the command_string operand. Set the value
>      of special parameter 0 (see Special Parameters) from the value
>      of the command_name operand and the positional parameters ($1,
>      $2, and so on) in sequence from the remaining argument
>      operands. No commands shall be read from the standard input.
> ```

Comment: Also, for me (and others), source doesn't work with the "sh" shell, but `bash -c ...` works great